# Proving that $M$ is a simple $R-$module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, group-actions, module-isomorphism

Here is the question I want to answer:

A module is simple if it is not the zero module and it has no proper nonzero submodule.

$(a)$ Let $M$ be an $R-$module. Show that the following conditions are equivalent.

1. $M$ is a simple $R-$module.
2. There exists a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m} \in R$ such that $M \cong_R R/ \mathfrak{m}.$
3. for any nonzero $x,y \in M$ there exists $r \in R$ such that $rx = y$ (i.e. the action of $R$ on $M$ is transitive).

**My trial is:**

$1 \implies 2$

Let $M$ be a simple $R-$module. We want to show that there exists a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m} \in R$ such that $M \cong_R R/ \mathfrak{m}.$

If $M$ is simple, then $0 \neq M$, so we can pick $x \in M, x \neq 0$. Then $Rx$ is a non-zero submodule of $M.$ Since $M$ is simple, we have $Rx=M$ as a simple module has no proper nonzero submodule   .

If we define $f: R \to M$ as $f(r)=rx$ then  clearly it is surjective (**is this correct in general or just because my $M$ is cyclic in that case**)and it is an $R-$module homomorphism because:

Let $r,s,r' \in R.$

$1- f(r + s) = (r + s)x = rx + sx = f(r) + f(s).$

$2- f(r'r) = (r'r)x = r'(rx) = r'f(r).$

Now, by the first isomorphism theorem, we have $R/\operatorname{Ker}(f) \cong \operatorname{im}(f)= M$.

Since we assumed that $R-$ module means left and right $R-$module i.e. $R$ is commutative, then we can prove the maximality of the ideal  $\mathfrak{m} = \operatorname{Ker}(f)$ as follows:

Since $R/\mathfrak{m}  \cong  M$ then it is simple, hence the only submodules (ideals) of $R/ \mathfrak{m}$ is $0$ and itself. This show that $R/ \mathfrak{m}$ is a field, so $\mathfrak{m}$ is maximal by a theorem.

**$2 \implies 3$**

Assume that there exists a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m} \in R$ such that $M \cong_R R/ \mathfrak{m}$ and we want to show that for any nonzero $x,y \in M$ there exists $r \in R$ such that $rx = y$ (i.e. the action of $R$ on $M$ is transitive)

Take the action of $R$ on $M$ as $f_x(r) = rx$ in the previous proof we said that $f_x$ is surjective and  hence for any nonzero $x,y \in M$ there exists $r \in R$ such that $rx = y.$

**My questions are:**

1- what is the precise reason for surjectivity of $f$?

2- Is my proof of **$2 \implies 3$** correct?

3- how can I prove **$3 \implies 1$**?

4- Is there is a better way of proving that question?

Could anyone help me in answering those questions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If $f$ is not surjective, then $Rx$ is a proper nonzero submodule of $M$, contrary to our assumption that $M$ is simple.
2. It could be better - it seems like you're using $1$ here instead of $2$. I think I'd go with the following: let $f:R\to R/\mathfrak{m}\cong M$ be the natural projection, and consider $Rx\subset M$ for some nonzero $x\in M$. Then $I=f^{-1}(Rx)$ is an $R$-submodule of $R$ (or, an ideal) which contains $\mathfrak{m}$. As $x\neq 0$, we must have that $I\neq \mathfrak{m}$: if $I=\mathfrak{m}$, then $f(I)=0$, but $x\neq 0$ is in $f(I)$. So $I=R$, and $f^{-1}(Rx)=R$, therefore $Rx=f(R)=M$ and there is some $r\in R$ with $rx=y$ for any $0\neq y\in M$.
3. Suppose $S\subset M$ is a nonzero submodule. We need to show that it's all of $M$. If it's not, then there's an $m\in M\setminus S$. Do you see where to go from here?

> Pick $s\in S$ and $r\in R$ so that $rs=m$. Thus $m\in S$, so $S=M$.

Comment: Nope. I cannot  see  the idea you are using for $3 \implies 1$ but let me read again for 3 minuits and give you my feedback

Comment: I used spoiler text so that you could ponder for a while and then see the answer at your leisure. Click on the spoiler text (it should say "Reveal spoiler") to see the solution.

Comment: Ok. thank you very much!

Comment: For $2 \implies 3, $ how did we use the assumptions of $2$ in the proof?

Comment: I guess that could be clearer, yeah. I think I'd go with the following: Define $R\to M$ by $r\mapsto rx$ for a nonzero $x\in M$. Then the image of this is a submodule of $M$, and it's inverse image in $R$ properly contains $\mathfrak{m}$ because it doesn't annihilate $x$. But that means it has to be all of $R$ because $\mathfrak{m}$ is a maximal ideal. So there's an $r\in R$ with $rx=y$.

Comment: And we were able to define this map because of the assumption .... correct?

Comment: To be honest still it is not so clear to me, do you have anyway of proving it in a more rigorous way?  specifically I need a rigorous proof of this statement "and it's inverse image in R properly contains m because it doesn't annihilate x. But that means it has to be all of R because m is a maximal ideal. "

Comment: how we are sure that it contains m in "and it's inverse image in R properly contains m because it doesn't annihilate x"? .... why $m$ is a maximal ideal implies that it has to be all of $R$  in " But that means it has to be all of R because m is a maximal ideal."?

Comment: Also, I want to ask is my proof of $1 \implies 2$ correct?

Comment: Is not proving the above statement of the problem by showing that $1$ equivalent to $2$ and $1$ equivalent to $3$ easier?

Comment: Sorry, one clarification - do you assume $R$ is commutative, or do you allow for non-commutative $R$?

Comment: We are assuming that $R-$module means left and right $R-$module .... so we have an assumption that $R$ is commutative. Does that make sense?

Comment: In your $3 \implies 1$ part, how we are sure that our module $M \neq 0$? is that because the action we have is a non-zero action?

Comment: Assuming that $R$-module means left and right $R$-module doesn't imply that $R$ is commutative on its own - $k^n$ is naturally both a left- and right-$M_n(k)$ module but $M_n(k)$ is not commutative for $n>1$. (The reason I asked is because if $R$ is commutative, then $R/\mathfrak{m}$ is a field, which makes 2 implies 3 pretty quick: just pick $r$ to be a lift of $y/x$.) For 3 implies 1, we should assume $M\neq 0$, which I did implicitly by supposing $S\subset M$ is not zero.

Comment: How $2 \implies 3 $ pretty quick by this fact? what do you mean by $r$ to be a lift of $y/x$?

Comment: If $R$ is commutative, then $R/\mathfrak{m}$ is a field, so if $x,y$ are nonzero then $y/x$ is a perfectly good element of $R/\mathfrak{m}$ which has the property that $(y/x)x=y$. So any $r\in R$ mapping to it under the quotient map $R\to R/\mathfrak{m}$ will give $rx=y$. (Given a map $X\to Y$, a lift of $y\in Y$ is a choice of $x\in X$ which maps to $y$. This is general.) Now, please, this comment thread is getting excessively long.